# Using $resource with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that I am calling to get a collection which works fine.  Here is the service:

```
angular.module('clinicalApp').factory('encounterService', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
  var EncounterService = $resource('http://localhost:port/v2/encounters/:encounterId', {encounterId:'@id', port: ':8280'}, {
    search: {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'User': 'testuser',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    },
    save: {
      headers: {
        'User': 'testuser',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  });

  return EncounterService;
});
```

As I said, I am able to get the collection, but when I try to update a one of the elements in my collection, it is calling out to the wrong url.  Here is how I am trying save my resource:

```
encounterService.save({
  id: scope.encounter.id
});
```

And here is the url that is being hit:

`http://localhost:8280/v2/encounters?id=12345`

So it is appending the url as if it is a search parameter.  How do I get it to append the id to the url like

`encounters/12345`

as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 {encounterId:'@id', port: ':8280'}
```

Change To:

```
 {encounterId:'@encounterId', port: ':8280'}
```

AND

```
 encounterService.save({
     id: scope.encounter.id
 });
```

Change To:

```
 encounterService.save({
     encounterId: scope.encounter.id
 });
```